# Making stroke of HTML Unicode (UTF-8) Reference icon thinner

Tags: css, html

I am trying to make the outer circle of this icon thinner. I got the circle from HTML Unicode (&#9711) and I scaled it up using `font-size: 30px;` to make it bigger. However, when it got bigger, the stroke also got effected

[image: Outer Circle]

Comment: Make the circle with `border-radius` instead of this.

Answer (score 2):

try like this

```css
div {
  border-radius:50%;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  font-size:30px;
}
```

```html
<div>&#8594</div>
```